# SCNView corner radius doesn't work on device

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, scenekit, radius

When I try to set `cornerRadius` property of `SCNView`, I don't get the expected result i.e. `SCNView` become rounded. It works properly on simulator but not on device. I checked on iPhone SE with iOS 13 and iPhone 7 with iOS 12 - result is the same on both. I wonder what can be the reason for this different behaviour on real device and simulator, and how can I get it working on device?

Comment: do you set `layer.masksToBounds = true` property?

Comment: yep, tried that, didn't help